# Get value from an array using find in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an array:

```
test = [{'id':'73','name':'bar', 'contact': [{'name':'barFoo','tel':'3333'}]},{'id':'45','name':'foo', 'contact':[]}]
```

I try to get contact.tel in first object with 'id':'73'

I'm using find method :

```
let contactTel = test.find(x => x.id === '73').contact.tel;
```

but it dosen't work. What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "it dosen't work".

Comment: You'r comparing the `string` `'73'` with the `number` `73`

Comment: `contact` is an array so you need `test.find(x => x.id === "73").contact[0].tel`

Comment: The contact property has no tel property.

Comment: Using `===` means that the **number** 73 is not the same as the **string** `"73"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be like this

```js
const test = [{'id':'73','name':'bar', 'contact': [{'name':'barFoo','tel':'3333'}]},{'id':'45','name':'foo', 'contact':[]}]


let contactTel = test.find(x => x.id === '73').contact[0].tel;

console.log(contactTel)
```